# exporting varbinary fileds with phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've had a little search but cant find an answer to my problem.

I'm attempting to backup my database which contains some columns that are varbinary data type, but when I import the backup all the varbinary fields are incorrect.

For example:

this is what is currently in the field:
f8cf723bd3a1fa8e99a5e291e9317809

and when I export it I get:
0xf8cf723bd3a1fa8e99a5e291e9317809

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 0x indicates that the field was dumped in hexadecimal notation, which is a way of encoding binary characters as standard text characters. Near the bottom of the export screen there is a checkbox that allows you to deselect the hexadecimal option if you desire

[image: Hexadecimal export option]

Have you tried to import and does it import correctly? Normally it should detect the hex encoding and import the values properly during the import process.

If you really want, you can read about hexadecimal notation in the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/hexadecimal-literals.html).

So basically, even though the export looks visually wrong, MySQL handles this properly on import and this is generally the desired behavior.

Comment: Ah I didn't try importing it again. Once I tried that, it all sorted itself out. Just shows I should have tried before asking the question. Thanks for explaining it aswel

Comment: Unchecking the hexadecimal notation export was a live saver for me. Thanks for this!

Comment: Changing my previous comment to:

Unchecking the hexadecimal notation export was a true live saver for me. Without it my imported database was completely corrupted when looking at multibyte characters. Thanks for this suggestion!